# white screen after clicking home menu button in drupal

Tags: 7

i am using **splashify module** (for customized front page) in drupal. after accessing the website content and then finally clicking the home menu button in drupal website going white screen display. then again pressing enter key only displaying the home page of the website. can any one suggested me how to rectify this problem. if i am not using splashify module, website working normally. please help

this is the website url : www.kodikunnilsuresh.in

Comment: Check your server logs, what error messages do you see? (please edit the question and add them)

Comment: i have checked the recent server logs but there is no error msg

Comment: You're getting a white screen, but there definitely aren't errors in the web server logs? Like 100% definitely? If so, you need to get whoever administers your server to turn error logging on, so you can debug further. Visiting the website isn't going to help, the errors will be logged on the server, not the client side

Comment: quick error reporting: <?php ini_set("display_errors", 1); ?> in your index.php to get started

Comment: i have check the recent log messages in drupal there is no error in that list. but once i have remove the splashify module its working fine. otherwise its displaying white screen and i have used in this line ini_set("display_errors", 1); in index.php file but its not showing any error